# Can I use PK/FK relationships to avoid having to use ON in JOINs?

Tags: t-sql

If I have my tables all defined with primary key and foreign key relationships, can I execute queries joining them together without specifying ON conditions in my JOINs?

If not, why not?

E.g.

```
Table fruit {
  id int [PK]
  name nvarchar(50)
}

Table person {
  id int [PK]
  name nvarchar(50)
  fruit_id int [ref: > fruit.id]
}

SELECT * 
FROM person JOIN fruit
```

Comment: Maybe you can do this, but why would you want to?  It might help if you add some sample data to your question.

Comment: No, you need to specify the `ON`. as for why, because  the data engine doesn't know what you want to join on; it can't read your mind. Just because you have a PK/FK relationship doesn't mean that'll be the criteria for your `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON` keyword is a required part of the `JOIN` syntax. This is similar to how a comparison operator is required in the syntax of a `WHERE` condition: Both are requirements in the underlying syntactical specifications.

Key relationships may assist the data engine in performing its operations by providing "tips" as to the organization and relationships of schema objects, but they do have any bearing on the syntax used to query for data contained in those objects.